# Placeholder implementation error

Tags: javascript, input, internet-explorer-9, textarea, placeholder

I have to set placeholders in textareas on a form using IE9. The problem im getting is that when the page is loaded, the text from the placeholder is being writen on the textarea rather than just being showed as just a gray text that disapears when the user write something on it. BUT, if I erase the text that is automatically writen, the placeholder works normally. Is this a common error? Is there a easy way to fix this?

Comment: Could you post your HTML code here? Need to see what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE9 doesn't support placeholder attribute. [See here](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder)

You will need to use JavaScript.
[See here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/form-placeholder-text/)

Comment: I am already using JS to to this. I solved my problems using getElementById.value = "" to when the page loads the textarea show as null. Thank you anyway!